# List of musicians who play left-handed

Tags: classical-music, electronic-music, live-music

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musicians_who_play_left-handed

Would it be rare where musicians can play the above musical instruments with either hand?

Comment: Your title merely states a fact. What is your actual question? The link you posted has a fairly long list of lefthanded players and is limited only to notable persons, so I'd argue this isn't that rare at all.

Answer (score 1):

Musicians who play ambidextrously are extremely rare, Wikipedia's [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musicians_who_play_left-handed) names only one who plays with either hand. Several other musicians on that list changed hands at some point and they might possibly have retained some facility with the other one. There are a couple of instruments, e.g. trumpet, where switching hands is trivial. A trumpet player with an injured right arm should be able to play left-handed at least well enough to practice until the injury has healed.